# Learning WPF GUI design

Tags: wpf, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What WPF books would you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend)

GUI's written using WPF seem to be closer to a Web 2.0 feel than older Winforms development has been; do you know of any good quality references online or books which give a general overview of how to design nice WPF applications?

I saw this StackOverflow question where some GUI design books are mentioned, but am interested in information specifically for WPF.

[Is WPF & SilverLight Design worth learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193001/is-wpf-silverlight-design-worth-learning)

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the other StackOverflow topic, that's a great list of books.  I am curious if there are any good online resources, since I'd like to get started in a hurry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found WPF Unleashed to be very UI-centric and WPF Control Development to be like the next step (very advanced GUI stuff).  The huge WPF book on Apress is great for in-depth coverage on the topic, but the red books on Sams would probably be better for what you're looking to get out of them.

[WPF Unleashed on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917)

[WPF Control Development Unleashed on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330334)

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably grab a copy of WPF Unleashed.  Know of any good online articles?

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/WPFTutorial.aspx) gives a good beginning intro. Even though it is for the 3.0 framework, the basics are all still valid.

This [one](http://wpf-training-guide.com/index.html), while not being a very good comprehensive guide, gives some good information on the different WPF controls.

There are many, many resources out there, but your best bet is still probably going to be at MSDN.  Now that VS2010 and the .NET framework have been released, MSDN has tons of tutorials and how-to videos on all the new stuff, including WPF.